# Tuning paramaters SVM, DT, k-NN, NN

Tags: parameterization

I'm trying to compare the predictive strenght of four different algorithms:

- support vector machines
- k-NN
- decision trees
- neural networks

I've got a few questions concerning the parameter tuning:

1. Some papers like [1]state that k-nearest neighbour does not need parameter tuning, don't you need to decide what k will be?
2. If you want to tune the parameters of SVM (gridsearch) and NN (different hidden neurons), on what data set do you do that if you plan on using tenfold cross-validation? If you're using your data set with tenfold, isn't there any data left to use to validate your parameters?

[1] Xiao, W., Qian, Z., & Fei, Q. (2006). A comparative study of data mining methods in consumer loans credit scoring management. Journal of Systems Science and Systems Engineering, 419-435.

Answer (score 1):

1. In kNN k is a parameter, so it can be selected via cross-validation, or it can just be chosen arbitrary, e.g. k=3 is a popular choice. If somebody says that kNN is parameterless, probably they mean 1NN, i.e. k=1.
2. Ideally you would have 3 datasets: one for choosing model structure and/or parameters (via cross-validation or hold out if you have enough data), one for training the models with the chosen structure/parameters, and  nominating the best model (also may be cross validation or hold out), and the third one for final testing (should be used once and once only).

Practically, if you have a small dataset this is often not feasible. Then the main idea is to make sure that after you chose the parameters, you train a new model on other dataset with the chosen parameters, and only then report the performance.

Comment: I have a dataset of 1000 instances. What if I would split that in three folds, and perform a cross-validation (training+validating) no 66% and testing on 33%, and do that 3 times?

Comment: What's the dimensionality? Generally, you are considering powerful models, 1000 is a small dataset. Try to maximize training set sizes. Maybe 10% for testing and do 10 times.